# Please help me understand the させたくない form

Tags: conjugations, causation

So I learned about させる, that it's like to influence someone to do something. Then we found this sentence on hunter x hunter.
ミトさんは （ゴンさんに）ハンター （を）受けさせたくない んだよ。

A bit of context, Mito don't want Gone to take the hunter exam. Now I would translate 受けさせたくない as "not want to force him to take it", but my teacher told me it was wrong. For a half hour, he tried to explain it to me but I still didn't get it.

Can you guys help me?
Thanks, Or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～させる can also mean "to let (someone) do~~" "to allow (someone) to do~~". See definition #2 in [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/29075/meaning/m0u/):

> させる
>   ・・・
>   ２ 〔望みどおりにさせる〕let ((a person do))，allow ((a person to do))
>   お前には好きなようにさせてやろう
>   I will *let* you do as you wish.
>   一言述べさせていただきます
>   *Let* me [*Allow* me to] say one thing.／I'd like to say one thing, if I may.

so how about translating it as...

> ミトさんは（ゴンさんに）ハンター（を）受けさせたくないんだよ。
>   "Mito-san doesn't want to *let* Gon-san take the hunter exam."

Comment: Would "Doesn't want to not let him take it" be 受けさせなくたくない?

Comment: @Nahcirn I don't think 「受けさせなくたくない」 makes any sense... You don't say 「～なくたく～」 or 「～なくたい」.

Comment: @Nahcirn that sentence seems unnecessarily convoluted and makes me take pause even reading it in english

Comment: I see, the させる stuff is really complicated.  "I don't want to force you" and "I don't want to let you" are written in the same way? there is a way to separate between these two meanings?

Comment: @Smiled_One Yes, they are written in the same way (Although させる usually means "let/allow" when you say させてもらう, させていただく, させてあげる, させてくれる etc, and "make/force/compel" when you say させられる), so 「受けさせたくない」 can mean either "don't want to let (him) take" or "don't want to force (him) to take". Here in your example "let/allow" just fits the context "Mito don't want Gone to take the hunter exam", so.. it'd usually be up to the context... Good luck! :)